# How to use qss to set radio button bold when checked?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to let the text of QRadioButton be bold when checked, but normal when not checked by using qss.

I tried this:

```
.QRadioButton {
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.QRadioButton:checked {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #AA0000;
}
```

When I checked the radio button, it's background color changed but not the font.
Does anyone know if I am doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Try to call `polish` / `unpolish` after changing a state of radio button. By default, changing font styles on fly is supported only for `QToolButtons` (as I remember)

Comment: I try `polish` / `unpolish` in a slot function which is connected to the `toggled` signal. It didn't work. At the end, I use a property to indicate the font `bold` / `normal` and `setProperty` in the slot function. It worked! I wonder the difference between **property** and **checked** state.

Answer (score 0):

Setting stylesheet property `font` to `normal` and `bold` should help.

```
QRadioButton {
    font: normal;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

QRadioButton:checked {
    font: bold;
    background-color: #AA0000;
}
```

The docs [do say](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#font-weight) that `font-weight` should work, though. You can file a bug for Qt company if that does not work for you. Setting `bold` and `normal` via composite [font](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#font) property is also legal and worked for me on many occurrences.

Comment: BTW was does dot in front of QRadioButton stand for? I never do that when I do widget->setStyleSheet("SomeWindget{  font:bold; }");

Comment: The dot means [class selector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types). It matches the instances of QRadioButton but not its subclasses. Instances of QRadioButton and its subclasses will be matched if the dot is not specified. Either way will not affect the result. The font of the radio button remains the same when checked.